# Weird join error on nav-menu-template.php on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting a weird PHP `join(): Invalid arguments passed` error on the `wp_nav_menu()` function when invoked in my theme file.

This is how I am calling it:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'depth' => 6, 
'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
'container' => 'ul', 
'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 
'menu_class' => 'nav fr', 
'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no "sort_column" param in this method

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu